# How to convert these PHP functions to C#?

Tags: c#, php

In PHP, you can write the following:

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
```

How do I do I write this in C#?

Also, how do I write this:

```
declare(ticks=1);
```

in C#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In c#, the timezone is built into the DateTime structure, so you should not need to set the default. Instead when you are manipulating DateTime instances you use the UTC version of methods. For example, in the constructor you can specify if the date supplied is local or UTC.

With regards to the second question, are you just wanting the syntax of

```
    int ticks = 1; // or
    var ticks = 1;
```

If you are trying to add a time period to a date, you should use a TimeSpan, along the lines of:

```
    TimeSpan ticks = new TimeSpan(1);
```